# using linklabel of a user control and pass the value to a form

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing inventory of animelist for fun and also for practice and I made a user control that consist of 1 linklabel and that link label will call a form and I need to pass the title of the linklabel to a label of that form all of my labels and link label was set to public.

[image]

[image]

here's my code and i'm using visual studio 2012 mysql database

```
    void ReadLabel()<br>
    {
        int ctr = 0;
        //string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlCommand command = myConn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Select * FROM maindatabase.animelist";
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?parameter",ctr.ToString()); 
       MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
           ctr++;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string Link = myReader["TitleAnime"].ToString();
                List li = new List();
                //AnimeForm ani = new AnimeForm();
                li.linkLabel1.Text = Link;
                li.linkLabel1.Click += linkLabel1_Click;
               // li.linkLabel1.Click = ani.Show();
                //if (li.linkLabel1.Text.Length > 0)
                //    li.linkLabel1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(li);
                button4.Enabled = false;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        myConn.Close();
    }

  void linkLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      AnimeForm ani = new AnimeForm();
      //ani.Title.Text = Link;
      ani.Show();
      //throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to pass the text property of the LinkLabel to the AnimeForm? ? If that is the case then you need to make the Label public so you are able to access it from other forms. To do that you have to change the Modifiers property in the properties window for **the Label in the AnimeForm.**

After that you will be able to access it in the way you are trying to:

```
void linkLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      AnimeForm ani = new AnimeForm();
      ani.Title.Text = Link;
      ani.Show();
  }
```

Hope this helps.

---

Ok. First of all, if your user control contains ONLY a link label and no additional logic or anything ... then you might as well just use link label. I am assuming that your user control is called List(kinda got me confused with another class). Also, as far as I can see, your data loading code is correct.

The problem is(forgive me for being Mr. Obvious if you already knew) is that your event handler doesn't get the correct value to give the new AnimeForm that it is creating.

What you need to do is get the Text of the object that is being clicked. For that you have the sender argument. You have to cast it to the type of the control that is calling this event handler, in this case LinkLabel. This will give you the LinkLabel that is being clicked. After that is done, you can simply access its Text(not sure if that is the one you need, but hopefully you get the point) property and give the value to the newly created form.

Here is what you need to do, if what I typed above makes no sense at all(I am not so good at explaining):

```
void linkLabel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          AnimeForm ani = new AnimeForm();
          ani.Title.Text = ((LinkLabel)sender).Text;
          ani.Show();
      }
```

Btw if you thought the explanation was too complicated for this simple expression, don't worry, I thought so too :D

Comment: Tnx for replying but i've already set all the labels and linklabels to public(modifier) and tried the code you provided it was already in a comment "//" if you notice..and what happen was it pass the last label..what i want to achieve was each animeform will pass each title..

Comment: What does the custom control actually look like(code and design)?

Comment: custom control for linklabel was linklabel only nothing else. my goal was retrieve all the data "titles" from database and store it on each linklabels(user control consist of 1 linklabel) and the click event of each label will call a new form called animeform and pass 1 title for each animeform consist of label(public)..i think my wrong codes are from retrieving the the data i think it has something to do with "using" and "foreach" statement..it would be gratefull if you could give me some ideas.

Comment: Please be sure to mark your question as answered if my answer helped you.